# Facebook Community receiving out of character join requests

Tags: new-members

I'm running a FB community focused on a very American/European-centric brand. It's  a community of about 10k members (though typical members in a group about this topic range to about 25k, we are niched down). We're getting a large number of requests from the Middle East. Often 50-100 in a given day. Any thoughts as to why? Any thoughts to how to easily screen them out or deter them?

(The typical user profile of this brand is a middle aged Caucasian woman with a moderate education.)

Answer (score 5):

Could be anything:

- Setting up connections used for marketing. If you are a connection, they can target you with adverts. In this case, spam the group with them.
- [Fishing for potential scam victims](https://www.facebook.com/help/616226325154941/), like mail-order brides, "I'm in country X without money" (the [stranded traveller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UP-KLRIJ-UA) scam that we know from email), [money mules](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3382212/Facebook-fraud-gangs-turn-gullible-middle-class-teenagers-criminal-money-mules-persuading-launder-cash-accounts.html), [lottery scams](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152461018638600), etc.
  This works best with direct friend connections, but this is tried in groups too. *Any* relationship between Facebook accounts increases the likelihood of someone falling for scams - most of this is done automatically so there's no price for trying.
- Establishing 'credit' for fake accounts. The more connections they have, the more legitimate they seem to be. This is often a side effect of [click farms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVfHeWTKjag) that sell fake likes. They subscribe to groups and [interact with random pages to 'dilute' their fake activities](https://thenextweb.com/facebook/2014/01/23/likes-lies-perfectly-honest-businesses-can-overrun-facebook-spammers/#.tnw_UnGTGCrn).
- [You can even be targeted for legitimate research](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2011/11/01/socialbot-network-harvest-data-facebook/) ;-)

More background on fake profiles:

- [10 Different Types of Fake Facebook Accounts](http://www.clickwhisperer.com/2014/04/04/the-10-types-of-fake-facebook-accounts/)
- [Facebook’s War Continues Against Fake Profiles and Bots](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/james-parsons/facebooks-war-continues-against-fake-profiles-and-bots_b_6914282.html)